# EF Core automatically converting ulong to long

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I have problem with entity framework core. I'm trying to add `DbUser` to database.

```
public class DbUser
{
    public int Id { get; set; } 
    public ulong DiscordId {get; set; }
    public int Points { get; set; } = 0;
    public bool Daily { get; set; } = true;
}


using (var context = new DiscordContext())
{
    context.Database.EnsureCreated();

    var user = new DbUser()
                   {
                       DiscordId = (ulong) 332282501902893056
                   };

    context.Users.Add(user);
    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

When I'm saving changes it throws an exception.

> System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'System.UInt64' to type 'System.Int64'.
>
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.ValueComparer`1.Equals(Object left, Object right)
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.ChangeDetector.LocalDetectChanges(InternalEntityEntry entry)
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.ChangeDetector.DetectChanges(IStateManager stateManager)
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.ChangeTracker.DetectChanges()
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.TryDetectChanges()
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.SaveChanges(Boolean acceptAllChangesOnSuccess)
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.SaveChanges()
> at bot.Program.Main(String[] args) in -----------------:line 22

I just can't add ulong value because it's automatically converted to long.

Comment: Can you show your db create table script pls?

Comment: Here's link https://pastebin.com/sabj9C4u

Comment: Does changing it to `long` work? `public long DiscordId {get; set; }`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Older versions (before feb 2o21) of EF Core don't support ulong.

I can  see in your  table User script that DiscordId table column is type long

```
  DiscordId = table.Column<long>(type: "bigint unsigned", nullable: false),
```

You just need to change DiscardId of your dbuser class to the same

```
 public long DiscordId {get; set; }
```

I found that MySql doesn't have UInt64, it has only Int64 type. So maybe you will have to use properties like this

```
[NotMapped]
public ulong DiscordId {
get {return DiscordDbId;}
set {DiscordDbId=(long)value; }
}

 [Column("DiscordId")]
 public long DiscordDbId {get; set; }
```

you can use DiscordDbId to work with dbcontext, but after this you can use DiscordId to work with your third party framework.

Comment: The problem for me is i just can't make it to happen, i tried migrating but nothing works i still have long in migration script.

Comment: Yes, it works but real problem for me is i cant put there `ulong` and if i will switch to `long` I would have to convert `ulong` to `long` when comparing, initialiazing etc. because DsharpPlus is returning `ulong` id of the user. Ef core version: 5.0.8

Comment: Did you try to change it manually inside of the create script ?

Comment: Still same reaction from debugger

Comment: You could add a `NotMapped` property to hide the cast. Or perhaps a value converter?

Comment: I never worked with MySql but now I found that it doesn't have UInt64, it has only Int64 type. It is impossible to use ulong for MySql.

Comment: I could do that but i was wondering if i can avoid it

Comment: Oh okay that clears everything, thanks for your help

Comment: @ISmellYu I updated my answer, I think it could work for you.